# PIPE is getting called multiple times, how can I make it called only once?

Tags: javascript, angular, pipe, angular-pipe

HTML : (component.html)

```
<input #CostInput class="form-element" formControlName="cost" [value]="replaceDecimal.transform(FormGroup.get('cost').value)">
```

Pipe.ts:

```
commaLocaleCodes = ['AM', 'AR'];
transform(input) {
        if (input) {
            const uiLanguage = 'am');
            if (this.commaLocaleCodes.indexOf(uiLanguage.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
                return input.replace(".", ",");
            } else {
                return input.replace(",", ".");
            }
        }
    }
```

Issue here is that Pipe gets called multiple times. If we send input = 123.45 . The pipe should return 123,45 and stop. But filter again gets called. And again input becomes 123.45.

Pipe is pure already. I want to understand if we can stop the pipe after first iteration. Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the pipe will be called every time the UI digest cycle refreshes.  If you want to call it once; you'll have to do so in the component code and store the value.  Of course, then any future changes on the input will not be reflected with the pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With default change detection strategy, the function bound to the property (or to a directive) will be triggered for each change detection cycle. This is the reason why it's discouraged to bind functions to properties and directives.

Instead invoke the function in the controller, save the response to a variable and use bind it in the template.

**Controller (*.ts)**

```js
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  transformedValue: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.transformedValue = this.replaceDecimal.transform(FormGroup.get('cost').value);
  }
}
```

**Template (*.html)**

```html
<input #CostInput class="form-element" formControlName="cost" [value]="transformedValue">
```

Comment: Tried pure = true , didn't work. Had to go with above method. Worked ! Thanks !

Comment: @Michael D, please, can you make a stackblitz? Really it's sounds me strange use `[value]` and `formControlName` together. I solve the problem using blur and focus, but I'm insterested in your code