# Why is the angular 11 async pipe not stabilizing with a delayed observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, async-pipe

I am subscribing to a delayed observable via async pipe in angular 11.

For some reason change detection(?) will not stabilize and the pipe will not receive the values and I can't figure out why?  Instead of showing my data it shows `null`.

example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-async-pipe-with-delay?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.html

html

```html
<h1>{{ getData(0) | async | json }}</h1>
```

component

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}
  getData(id: number) {
    return this.dataService.getDataDelayed(id).pipe(tap(console.log));
  }
}
```

service

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 0,
    data: 'hello'
  }
];

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  constructor() {}

  getDataDelayed(id: number) {
    return of(data[id]).pipe(delay(5000)); // works fine without the delay
  }
}
```

Comment: _"change detection(?) will not stabilize"_ - this is a well known behavior when binding functions in directives or invoked in interpolation. Please refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66707617/6513921

Comment: it is the same with onPush. However I would still expect my values to be shown. I also want to leverage the async pipe without component subscriptions. Nothing else triggers changeDetection and without the delay it does stabilize.

Comment: The problem is the following: In the moment the service returns the data, a new change detection cycle is triggered. This causes your method `getDataDelayed()` to be called again. In that moment, the observable is overridden with a new one (because a new request is started), which does not have a value yet and therefore displays as `null`.

Comment: @Markus: The delay within the function call is the issue. See here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-async-pipe-with-delay-vtbe3e?file=src/app/_services/data.service.ts

Comment: @MichaelD you eliminated the need for calling the function by removing the abillity to pass through id. that of course bypasses the problem :)

Comment: here is a more real-world example of what I am trying to do: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-async-pipe-with-delay-real-world?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to be careful when you use the async pipe on a function call.
The async pipe keeps a reference to the observable and subscribes to it. When you use the getData function call, a new observable is created each time there's a change detection, and so the async pipe subscribes to the new observable and doesn't wait for the previous one anymore.

What you could do change the getData method to keep a reference to the observable so it always return the same observable for a given id.

```js
  private data: Observable<any>[] = [];

  getData(id: number) {
    if (!this.data[id]) {
      this.data[id] = this.dataService
        .getDataDelayed(id)
        .pipe(tap(console.log));
    }
    return this.data[id];
  }
```